# AngularJS send request x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a Django server amd I am trying to send a request to it using AngularJS.

This is my code:

```
           var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/register/',
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: $.param({ phone_number: phonenumber, password: phonenumber, country: 1 })
            }

           $http(req).then(function(response){
                callback(response);
            }, function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
```

I am getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/register/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am not sure what can be the problem here. I already created an applications for iOS and Android that both communicate with the same server and I didn't have any problems.

I am using AngularJS 1.5.5 https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/

Can someone suggests what is wrong with this request in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the code didn't need this part:

`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',`

The real problem was because the server wasn't allowing local urls.